# why does explode function transforms value?

Tags: php, explode

I have this little explode process:

```
$var = 120.180;
$var = explode("." , $var);
$var1 = $var[0];
$var2 = $var[1];

echo $var1;
echo $var2;
```

the echo is:

120 and 18, why? Why is 180 transformed to 18 and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because 120.180 is not a string, it's a number. So 120.180 will become 120.18 - because the zero is a floating point value. You'll find that just echoing 120.180 will still produce 120.18.

If you did `$var = "120.180";`, I.E. used quotes around the number, you'd get the result you're expecting.

Comment: This actually answered the question rather than just providing a solution and redundant may be an incorrect word, here it gets rid of `0` because its a floating value... so php rounds up to `120.18`

Answer (score 2):

Put the value in quotes to use $var as a string:

```
$var = '120.180';
```

Now you're saving 120.180 as some floating point value, which will cut of the trailing zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try it again with the $var as a string:

```
$var = '120.180';
```

Comment: @PaulLo: because with 120.180, the value is a float, so 120.180 = 120.18

Comment: @bh42: Actually, 120.180 is a float or double, certainly not an integer.

Comment: @cguedel: you're right, I wrote it too fast, corrected it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$var` does not contain what you expect. Consider the following code:

```
$var = 120.180;
var_dump($var);
```

This will output `float(120.18)` -- you can see that it removed the zero already. That's how numbers are stored in PHP.

Store the number as a string if you want to preserve `0`s.

```
$var = '120.180';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix it. It's broken to begin with. Start with something different instead.

```
$var = '120.180';
$var = explode("." , $var);
$var1 = $var[0];
$var2 = $var[1];

echo $var1;
echo $var2;
```